# Spring -- inject 2 beans of same type

Tags: java, spring

I like constructor-based injection as it allows me to make injected fields `final`. I also like annotation driven injection as it simplifies my `context.xml`. I can mark my constructor with `@Autowired` and everything works fine, as long as I don't have two parameters of the same type. For example, I have a class:

```java
@Component
public class SomeClass {
    @Autowired(required=true)
    public SomeClass(OtherClass bean1, OtherClass bean2) {
        …
    }
}
```

and an application context with:

```xml
<bean id="bean1" class="OtherClass" />
<bean id="bean2" class="OtherClass" />
```

There should be a way to specify the bean ID on the constructor of the class `SomeClass`, but I can't find it in the documentation.  Is it possible, or am I dreaming of a solution that does not exist yet?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`@Autowired` is by-type (in this case); use `@Qualifier` to autowire by-name, following the example [from spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html):

```
public SomeClass(
    @Qualifier("bean1") OtherClass bean1, 
    @Qualifier("bean2") OtherClass bean2) {
    ...
}
```

> Note: In contrast to @Autowired which is applicable to fields, constructors and multi-argument methods (allowing for narrowing through qualifier annotations at the parameter level), @Resource is only supported for fields and bean property setter methods with a single argument. As a consequence, stick with qualifiers if your injection target is a constructor or a multi-argument method.

(below that text is the full example)

Comment: `@Autowire` is by-name too, but in that case you need to provide setters. But here constructor arguments is preferred, and `@Autowire` will not work if both args are of same type. Hence, the thing can be solved using `@Qualifier`.

Comment: It's the Spring @Qualifier, *not* the standard one javax.inject.Qualifier

Comment: @Qualifier not working in constructor injection , is it dependent on variable name in constructor for eg  `public Employee(String name, int age, @Qualifier("address1") Address address)` address1 is not injected ?