# Spring instantiate object with constructor arguements using java-config (not XML)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I get Spring to instantiate a bean that does not have a no-argument constructor?  I'm using java-config (not xml-config).  It seems to work using XML -but shouldn't I be able to do the same thing with annotations somehow?

Straight from the tutorial, the following example is the equivalent in xml-config:

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="examples.ExampleBean">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="7500000"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="42"/>
</bean>
```

It also mentions the use of @ConstructorProperties annotation, which I've tried to use -but I can't get it to work.  I keep getting a BeanInstantiationException.

Comment: please post the code you tried with @ConstructorProperties annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ExampleBean exampleBean() {
        return new ExampleBean(7500000, 42);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "my.properties" })
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Value("{prop.value1}")
    private int value1;
    @Value("{prop.value2}")
    private int value2;

    @Bean
    public ExampleBean exampleBean() {
        return new ExampleBean(value1, value2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also from the link below
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/ConstructorProperties.html

what i understood is, @ConstructorProperties annotation is not to be used as a replacement for your xml-config.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `@Autowired` with `@Qualifier`, like in another [SO Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153657/spring-dependency-injection-in-construcor-with-annotations)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Autowired or @Inject