# Spring MVC 5: Ambiguous mapping found using new Spring MVC Annotations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I couldn't see where the ambiguous mapping problem is in here. I'm using new Spring MVC annotations @GetMapping and @PostMapping in my Controllers, since I changed Spring version to 5.0.0M1.

- WebXml.java

  ```
  public class WebXml implements WebApplicationInitializer {
  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webXml = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      webXml.register(WebAppConfig.class);

      DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(webXml);
      dispatcherServlet.setContextConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml");

      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("mvc-dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");

      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(webXml));

      /** This is useful because current browsers typically do not - set a 
          character encoding even if specified in the HTML page or form */
      Dynamic filter = container.addFilter("encodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
      filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, Boolean.FALSE, "/*");
      filter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");

  }
  ```

  }
- AbstractPessoaController

  ```
  public abstract class AbstractPessoaController extends AbstractController {

  protected final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

  @Override
  protected void init(WebDataBinder binder) {
      SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtil.DD_MM_YYYY);
      binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(df, Boolean.TRUE));
      binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "celular",  new TelefoneEditorSupport());
  }

  protected void criaPessoaPadrao(Pessoa pessoa) {
      pessoa.gerarCodigo();
      pessoa.setSexo(Sexo.MASCULINO);
      Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
      pessoa.setUsuario(usuario);
      usuario.setPessoa(pessoa);
  }
  ```

  }
- AlunoController.

  ```
  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/aluno")
  public class AlunoController extends AbstractPessoaController {

  public static final String ALUNO_LISTA = "aluno-lista";
  public static final String ALUNO_CADASTRO = "aluno-cadastro";
  public static final String ALUNO_HOME = "aluno.home";

  @Autowired
  private AlunoService service;

  @GetMapping
  public String cadastro(Model model) {
      Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
      criaPessoaPadrao(aluno);

      model.addAttribute("aluno", aluno);
      adicionaSexoAoModel(model);

      return ALUNO_CADASTRO;
  }

  @GetMapping("/lista")
  public String lista(Model model) {
      List<Aluno> alunos = service.findAll();
      model.addAttribute("alunos", alunos);

      return ALUNO_LISTA;

  }

  @PostMapping
  public String cadastroSubmit(Model model, @Valid Aluno aluno, BindingResult result) {
      model.addAttribute("aluno", aluno);
      adicionaSexoAoModel(model);

      if (result.hasErrors()) {
          return ALUNO_CADASTRO;
      }

      gravar(aluno, model);


      return ALUNO_CADASTRO;

  }

  private void gravar(Aluno aluno, Model model) {
      try {
          service.gravar(aluno);
          mensagemConfirmacao(model);
      } catch (NegocioException e) {
          LOG.error("Erro ao tentar gravar o aluno. ", e);
          mensagemErro(e.getMessage(), model);
      }
  }

  @Override
  protected void init(WebDataBinder binder) {
      super.init(binder);
      binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "altura",  new CustomNumberEditor(Double.class, Boolean.FALSE));
  }

  private void adicionaSexoAoModel(Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("sexo", CollectionUtils.arrayToList(Sexo.values()));
  }
  ```

  }

And I'm getting an exception:

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'alunoController' bean method 
public java.lang.String br.com.activepersonal.AlunoController.cadastro(org.springframework.ui.Model)
to {[/aluno],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'alunoController' bean method**
public java.lang.String br.com.activepersonal.AlunoController.lista(org.springframework.ui.Model) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)

another error is happening is:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:277)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Any help How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the bean in the XML too?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635244/there-is-already-bean-method-mapped

Comment: hey @bphilipnyc, thank you for reply. No, I don't have my controllers in XML.

Comment: what is AbstractController? Can you show that class as well?

Comment: Hello @BrianClozel, I updated my post adding AbstractController class. Any Idea? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Another error is happening is

Comment: Hey @ValdemarJúnior! How you fix this issue?

Comment: Hey DeepakAgrawal, I haven't fixed this issue yet. I'm just using @RequestMapping, because I couldn't find a solution in time to release the project.