# How to perform Constructor Injection in this scenario?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, constructor-injection

Suppose we have a class Name A.java. In A.java class we have a default constructor

```
A(){
}
```

and one custom constructor have a parameter like

```
A(B b){
super(b);
}
```

Now class C is extending class A to use the getter of the A class. Again C has a constructor  with one parameter like

```
C(A a)
{
 this.a = a;
}
```

Again we have one class D , in this we have a constructor like

```
D(C c )
{this.c = c;
}
```

Now My question is how we can perform spring construction injection in this scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring dependency injection in construcor with annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153657/spring-dependency-injection-in-construcor-with-annotations)

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Do you want all to create beans for all classes or just class D? Do you want to have everything in XML or to use annotations?

Comment: Somewhat vague. Could you please elaborate and provide a more complete (compilable) example? So C both extend A (and also delegates to some A?). I suppose your class hierarchy is just too complex - in Spring, you'd rather use composition than inheritance.

Comment: @Tomasz W I want every thing in applicationContext.xml

Comment: @TomaszW I want to create a bean to all class

Comment: @GyroGearless My requirement is different but i have use alphabets to clearly usderstand the issues.

Comment: can any one write some prototype for xml file relating to my requierement. That will help me alot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the context I wrote:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="a" class="com.my.springtest.A">
        <constructor-arg ref="b"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="b" class="com.my.springtest.B"/>

    <bean id="c" class="com.my.springtest.C">
        <constructor-arg ref="a"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="d" class="com.my.springtest.D">
        <constructor-arg ref="c"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Save this file and put it into your classpath(eg. src/main/resources if you use maven). Then you can create this context in junit:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test-context.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SpringTest {

    @Autowired
    private D d;

    @Test
    public void testBean() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(d);
    }
}
```